# Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH: no backstack?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'd like to start an activity for e web search. Instead of firing up a browser with a google query, I'd rather like to use thismore universal approach:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query); // query contains search string
startActivity(intent);
```

But, much to my surprise, the back button brings me from the search to the home screen. And not to the app back, as it does with ACTION_VIEW.

Basic question: how to achieve to get the current activity on the backstack, when using Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I made small walkaround. The code below check if text you wanna search is web URL or not. If it is URL - this website will be opened. If it's not URL - it will paste it to google search box and show search results.

This code was tested for API 21+

```
private void searchOnGoogle(String query){
        Uri uri;
            if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(query).matches()) // checks if text is ULR
            {
                uri = Uri.parse(query);
            }
            else {
                uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.pl/search?q="+query);
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // R.string.error - string resource with text you wanna display to user when intent won't run
            }
```